# Foreach Through QJsonObject to get Key/Value Pair

Tags: c++, qt

I am wondering how I would `foreach` through a `QJsonObject` to get the key/value pairs in C++? So far, I am only able to get the value.

```
//main.cpp
QFile file(":/geoip.json");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray rawData = file.readAll();
file.close();
QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));
QJsonObject json = doc.object();
foreach(const QJsonValue &value, json) {
    QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
    qDebug() << value;
}

//geoip.json
{
    "Afghanistan": "58.147.159.255",
    "Albania": "31.22.63.255",
    "Algeria": "105.235.143.255",
    "American Samoa": "202.70.115.241",
    "Andorra": "109.111.127.255",
    "Angola": "105.175.255.255",
    "Anguilla": "208.66.50.44",
    "Antarctica": "46.36.195.10"
}
```

Comment: the keys method returns the top level keys. in your case json.keys()

Comment: @johnelemans Awesome, thank you. I can accept your solution as the answer if you post it below :)

Answer (score 25):

John already gave the answer. Using keys() a complete working solution would be:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //main.cpp
    QFile file("path/to/geoip.json");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QByteArray rawData = file.readAll();
    file.close();
    QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));
    QJsonObject json = doc.object();
    foreach(const QString& key, json.keys()) {
        QJsonValue value = json.value(key);
        qDebug() << "Key = " << key << ", Value = " << value.toString();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that calling .keys() causes QT to iterate the entire map, and return a QList each and every time you call it. It would be more efficient to use keyBegin() / keyEnd() to iterate the keys in-place, especially if the code is called frequently

Comment: Note: there is no keyBegin()/keyEnd() in Qt 5...

Comment: And so, 6 years later, there is no way to iterate over a json object, obtaining both key and value. Something like std::map's iterators.
the json.keys() / json.value(key) approach looks strange - does it do a lookup in the json for each json.value(key) call?

Comment: @Nuclear If I understood your remark correctly, the answer below should be appropriate, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but to answer **Nuclear**
With the method proposed by **Twisq** it is possible to browse a JSON by obtaining the keys and values ​​without problem.
But you are talking about iterating a JSON...?
With "QJsonObject::const_iterator" objects it is possible with the code below:

```
#include<QJsonDocument>
#include<QJsonObject>
#include<QFile>

int main (int nbArg, char* listArg[])
{
  QFile file("my_file.json");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QByteArray rawData = file.readAll();
  file.close();
  QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));
  QJsonObject myJson = doc.object();

  QJsonObject::const_iterator myIterator = myJson.constBegin();
  QJsonObject::const_iterator myIteratorEnd = myJson.constEnd();

  do
  {
    qDebug() << myIterator.key();
    qDebug() << myIterator.value();
    myIterator++;
  }
  while(myIterator!=myIteratorEnd);
}
```